Behaviour of std::is_sorted function in C++
Consider the following C++ program which checks whether the given array is sorted or not.
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
int main()
{
    std::vector<float> array = {1.1, 2.2,3.3, 3.3, 5.5};    
    std::cout<<std::is_sorted(array.begin(), array.end(), [](float  a, float b){std::cout<<"a: "<<a<<"\b: "<<b<<std::endl; return a < b;});
    
    return 0;
}

Since there are two equal values, I expected that is_sorted would return false. But to my surprise, it returned true. If I change a<b to a<=b, it returns true!
I also expected that the parameters in the lambda function would be in the order of the original array. But it turned out the other way. That is, a=2.2 and b=1.1 in the first iteration.
Can somebody explain these behaviors?

a<=b -- Using this leads to undefined behavior due to this comparison violating the strict-weak-ordering requirements.  So your results using this are basically meaningless.

"I also expected that the parameters in the lambda function would be in the order of the original array. But it turned out the other way." Implementation specific, but given a < b, when we want to check for c <= d, we do !(d < c) (so the "reverse" order).

Ok...I understand. But a<b should override the default "non-descending" behavior of the function "is_sorted" to strictly "ascending" ...right?

BTW, I just ran your code with a<=b using Visual C++.  In debug builds, I get the dreaded "invalid comparator" abort message box when I run the program.

@Soo No. The library expects the comparator to be a strict less-than operator, and in such case std::is_sorted returns whether the array is non-descending. You expect the library to return comp(v[0],v[1]) && comp(v[1],v[2]) && ... but that's not what the library does. If it did that, you could indeed choose a weak or strict comp, and check for non-decreasing or strictly-increasing orderings, as you expect. But it does not. You can read the possible implementation of is_sorted_until (version 2) to see it.

In that possible implementation, the library does something like !comp(v[1],v[0]) && !comp(v[2],v[1]) && .... Effectively, it uses !comp(b,a) to check a<=b, assuming comp is strict less-than.

std::is_sorted works in correspondence with std::sort; if you std::sort(begin, end, predicate), then std::is_sorted(begin, end, predicate) will be true. It would be a pretty useless function if it were false with a newly sorted range.

std::is_sorted :

Checks if the elements in range [first, last) are sorted in non-descending order.

(emphasys is mine)
Non-descending allows for consecutive equal elements.
The comparator:

returns ​true if the first argument is less than (i.e. is ordered before) the second.

Note that it should respect the named requirement Compare which implies strict weak-ordering.
One of the requirements for strict weak-ordering is:

it is irreflexive: for all x, r(x, x) is false

The version that uses <= does not respect it (because x <= x and so your comparator will return true for (x,x)), and therefore leads to undefined behavior.

But I tried to customize the behavior by using the lambda function as shown, which is supposed to override the default behavior....right?

See my updated answer with more info about it.

@Soo: You can customize what "non-descending" means, e.g. if you have roman numerals in a std::string. But even then MXII < MXII has to be false.

@wohlstad: Thanks for the explanation. Now it makes  sense to me:)

Thanks for the explanation. Now it makes sense to me:). What is your comment on my other observation that the order of the parameters in the compare function (here lambda function) is in the reverse order? @Jarod42 mentioned in his comment that it is implementation-specific. If so, we will have a problem writing portable code. Can you throw some light on it?

@Soo as Jarod42 commented, the standard does not specify how the algortithm is exactly implemented (e.g. it could compare each element to the next one instead of the previous one, and the order would change). But this is not a problem for writing portable code. As long as your compare function respects strict weak ordering the result would be the same.

@Soo if an answer solves your problem you could click '✔' to mark it as an accepted answer. You can also upvote any helpful answer (voting and accepting is separate). See here: What should I do when someone answers my question?.

As is already mentioned, the comparison is non-descending. Looking at the code you posted though, and running it through 3 major compilers (see https://godbolt.org/z/W4nWs1hrc), you can see that the output is:
a: 2.2: 1.1
a: 3.3: 2.2
a: 3.3: 3.3
a: 5.5: 3.3
1

Thus, you can see that is not comparing array[0] < array[1], it's actually comparing array[1] < array[0], so when it gets to your 3.3s, it will return false, which actually allows it to continue. If, however, the predicate returned true, it would actually cause the loop to stop, and then the entire function would return false.
In the case of <=, you can see that it actually returns false in the same three compilers (https://godbolt.org/z/9e9qhM455), however, it should be noted that this is actually UB. MSVC, when built in debug, will product a runtime error here, since it checks that:
if ( Pred( left, right ) ) {
    verify( !Pred( right, left ) );
}


Originally I though this is the issue. But the 3rd comparison (3.3 vs 3.3) will return true with <=. I think the issue here is actually UB due to breaking strict weak ordering.

@wohlstad, true that it would be UB, but I left mention of the <= out of the answer because of that. I was more referencing the Since there are two equal values, I expected that is_sorted would return false. part of the question, and looking at how it's done from an implementation point of view (of course, standard doesn't specify how, just what). Edited to clarify.


Since there are two equal values, I expected that is_sorted would return false. But to my surprise, it returned true.

As you discovered, is_sorted does not check for duplicates. But if a sequence is sorted according to is_sorted, then duplicate will be adjacent, and std::adjacent_find will find those.
Note that the predicate for std::adjacent_find is an equality predicate, not a strict weak ordering. You may want to check out operator<=> to avoid having to write two comparison operators for your own classes.
